# Tomcat: Doesnt pick up SSL certificate without port-number

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate, port-number

I am having an issue with getting Tomcat to use the new SSL certificate (from GoDaddy).
Tomcat is picking up the new certificate only when I mention the portnumber (say unit1.myfirm.net:8443).
It does not do so when I try just the URL (say unit1.myfirm.net).

Any ideal why?
Thanks for time!

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP` and `HTTPS` have a default port number. When you use `http://unit1.myfirm.net` url in your browser automatically the `port 80` is used, when you type `https://unit1.myfirm.net` url `port 443` is used instead. In the other hand you can configure the port for http and https in tomcat, so in your case probably you just config the `port 8443` for the `https` in your tomcat not the `443`. This is why you've to use the port in the url: `https://unit1.myfirm.net:8443`.

If you want to specify the 443 for the ssl, you have to edit the `server.xml` which is located in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`. In this file there is a connector like:

```
<Connector
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    port="8443" maxThreads="200"
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="/path/keystore" keystorePass="yourPass"
    clientAuth="true" sslProtocol=..... />
```

Change the port attribute from `port="8443"` to `port="443"`

Hope this helps,